# Version issues while installing node packages

Tags: nodejs, versions, npm

I'm trying to install mongoose. I have rechecked my node and NPM versions and they are LTS versions. I have tried to use `nvm use --lts` too. But still I'm facing this issue which I attached below.

[image]

Comment: What happens if you run sudo node --version? It could be that sudo has a different node version installed and it's not recommended to install packages using sudo unless you want to install them globally I believe.